# Issue while building a dynamic xpath in selenium + python

Tags: python, selenium, xpath

I have written a dynamic XPath as shown below:-

```
    _FIRST_LIKE_TEXT_XPATH = "(//*[starts-with(@class,'%s-message')]/div/p)[%s]"
    print(f"FIRST_LIKE_TEXT_XPATH with action and iteration = {self._FIRST_LIKE_TEXT_XPATH % action % str(itr)}") 

action = like and itr = 1
```

expected output = (//*[starts-with(@class,'like-message')]/div/p)[1]

The error I am getting:-

> TypeError: not enough arguments for format string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use the python [format](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_string_format.asp) function to pass variable in a string.

```
_FIRST_LIKE_TEXT_XPATH = "(//*[starts-with(@class,'{}-message')]/div/p)[{}]".format(action,str(itr))
```